# Non-Hebrew Torah commentary

Tags: hebrew, commentaries

There is a teaching that only Torah commentary written in Hebrew, the holy tongue, will endure.

However, the entire Talmud and the Book of Daniel are not in Hebrew, but in Aramaic.  Even some parts of our liturgy are in Aramaic (Kaddish, Ha Lachma, Echad mi Yodea, Be Anna Rachitz, etc.)

Why is Aramaic getting a pass?  If you say it's because it is very close to Hebrew, then so is Arabic, and the Rambam wrote everything (except the Mishneh Torah) in Arabic.

We must conclude that the teaching must have come much later.  When did it come and what was the motivation?

Comment: Where can this teaching be found?

Comment: I'll try to retrace it, but it must be related to the teaching in Shabbat 12b that the angels do not understand Aramaic.

Comment: Aramaic is special, Adam spoke it: Sanhedrin 38b

Comment: Would be interested in finding the source for this. As an aside, this statement just is fairly common sense as Hebrew and Aramaic are common to the entire Jewish people (via Tanach, Targum, Midrashim and Shas) while Arabic, Yiddish, Ladino, English, Polish, Russian, German, etc. were limited to subsections of the Jewish people.

Comment: As a relevant aside, does anybody know of an authoritative non-ancient commentary written in a language other than Hebrew?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi there has been a lot of authoritative Torah written in, at least in part, yiddish, such as chassidic discourses

Comment: Have they been translated into Hebrew?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi yes, I will find you specific examples if you let me know what you are getting at?

Comment: Just want to know if that teaching (if it exists -- you guys make me doubt, but I DID hear it) is taken seriously.

Comment: I believe R' Hirsch's commentary was originally written in German.

Comment: @Yehuda on that note, the Rambam wrote Peirush HaMishnayos in Arabic (and iirc other sefarim as well)

Comment: I never heard such a teaching. I doubt it exists.